# Eliminar texto despues de ==

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed

Un archivo de requisitos [pip](/questions/tagged/pip) contiene todos los paquetes instalados en  Python, de modo que dicho archivo pueda usarse en otro lugar y reconstruir el entorno de programación original.

Un archivo de requisitos se ve así:

```
alabaster==0.7.9
arrow==0.8.0
awesome-slugify==1.6.5
Babel==2.3.4
binaryornot==0.4.0
blessings==1.6
```

Lo que quiero es eliminar la parte que indica la versión, en el caso de la primera línea `alabaster==0.7.9`, eliminar la parte `==0.7.9` y dejar solo `alabaster`.

Entiendo que al encontrar una coincidencia se crean dos grupos, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar. Lo estoy intentando en [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) usando [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) de la siguiente manera.

1. Cuando pido el primer grupo:

   ```
   $ awk -F"==" '{print $1}' base.txt
   ```

   obtengo esto:

   ```
   alabaster==0.7.9
   arrow==0.8.0
   awesome-slugify==1.6.5
   ```

   es decir, se repite el archivo.
2. Cuando pido el segundo grupo con

   ```
   $ awk -F"==" '{print $2}' base.txt
   ```

   solo obtengo 50 líneas en blanco.

### ADICIÓN:

Ahora busco con este patrón `(\w+)(==.)` con lo que hago dos grupos de match, estoy interesado en el primero. Pero si el el paquete se llama `python-mimeparse` ya no hay *match*. *Debería poder agregar guiones por si algún paquete se llama `paquete_python` o `paquete-python`*.

#### Adenda 2

Esta expresión `(.+)(==)(.+)` encuentra tres grupos, el primero es el paquete (que es lo que busco) y el tercerlo es la versión. Ahora solo necesito saber cómo usarlo en `awk`.

#### tercera edición

Publiqué una respuesta que resuelve el problema en Python, pero la idea es que la solución se aplique con alguna otra herramienta como `awk`, `gawk`, `sed` o incluso `perl`.

En esta publicación de [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern) aparecen varias opciones, pero no he podido usar mi patrón de búsqueda en ninguna. No obtengo errores, pero tampoco algún resultado.

#### Alguas consideraciones:

- Busco obtener **solo el nombre del paquete**, no la versión
- No hay ningún paquete instalado, por lo que no hay nada que actualizar
- La solución puede usar otra herramienta, como `sed` o `grep`

Comment: uh... yo probé tu primer snippet  `awk -F"==" '{print $1}' base.txt` y salió exactamente como tú lo querías

Comment: @toldeano, concuerdo con amenadiel, [mira](https://i.stack.imgur.com/549jE.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución `awk -F'==' '{print $1}' archivo` utiliza un separador de campos ([FS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html)) con multicaracteres. Esto es válido siempre y cuando estés utilizando una versión de `awk` compatible con POSIX. Por ejemplo, en Solaris no funcionará.

Entonces la cuestión es: ¿cómo hacerlo funcionar?

Pues simplifiquemos: el fichero consiste en líneas de la forma `módulo==versión`. Por ello, lo que podemos hacer es eliminar `=` y todo lo que lo sigue:

```
$ cut -d'=' -f1 fichero
alabaster
arrow
awesome-slugify
Babel
binaryornot
blessings
```

Esto está diciendo: separa la línea basándote en `=` como separador (`-d=`) e imprime el primer campo resultante (`-f1`).

Puede ser un poco frágil, por lo que también puedes optar por utilizar `sed`:

```
sed 's/=.*//' fichero
```

Esto hace lo mismo: elimina a partir del primer símbolo `=`. Sin embargo permite ampliar el comando a algo más complejo como:

```
$ sed '/==/s/=.*//' fichero
alabaster
arrow
awesome-slugify
Babel
binaryornot
blessings
```

Que realiza esta sustitución solo en las líneas que contengan `==`. Y si me apuras, puedes llegar a decir:

```
sed -n '/==/s/=.*//p' fichero
```

Para imprimir solamente estas líneas (`-n` inhibe la impresión por defecto y `p` imprime la línea actual).

---

Si realmente quieres utilizar `match()` de awk, utiliza:

```
$ awk 'match($0, /^(.+)==(.+)/, res) {print res[1]}' fichero
alabaster
arrow
awesome-slugify
Babel
binaryornot
blessings
```

Como ves, la sintaxis es `match(línea, patrón, matriz de resultados)`. Por tanto, es cuestión de capturar los que nos interesen: en este caso solamente el primero, por lo que de hecho podríamos limitarnos a decir `match($0, /^(.+)==/, res)`, sin necesidad de capturar el resto.

---

En resumidas cuentas: `awk` no parece la mejor solución aquí porque en según qué entornos puede que te dé problemas el separador de campos con multicaracteres. Hazte la vida fácil usando `sed` en este caso: no hace falta utilizar expresiones regulares tan complejas cuando un `sed` sencillito ya te da todo lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 3):

**A. VALORES DE LA IZQUIERDA DE ==**

***Opción 1.***

Capturar todo lo que está antes de ==

```
^.*?(?=\=\=)/gm
```

***Opción 2.***

Hacer un match sin capturar el grupo a partir de ==

Gracias @fedorqui

```
^.*?(?:==)/gm
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/AVCmvW/6)

**Resultado**

> ```
> alabaster
> arrow
> awesome-slugify
> Babel
> binaryornot
> blessings
> ```

**B. VALORES DE LA DERECHA DE ==**

**`=.*`**

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/AVCmvW/1)**

**Resultado**

> ```
> ==0.7.9
> ==0.8.0
> ==1.6.5
> ==2.3.4
> ==0.4.0
> ==1.6
> ```

Comment: Gracias @ACedano, busco seleccionar la primera parte, o sea el nombre de los paquetes.

Comment: @toledano Prueba el nuevo regex actualizado.  No pude hacerlo funcionar en una sola línea, por eso tiene el flag `/gm` al final.

Comment: No estoy convencido de que el look-ahead sea correcto. Probablemente quieras utilizar `^.*?(?=\=\=)` para indicar: coge todo hasta encontrar `==`.

Comment: @fedorqui Funciona tanto el mío (A), como el tuyo. Puedes verlo en el DEMO.

Comment: Si le añades una línea del tipo `hola=adios` te devolverá el falso positivo "hola". Esto es porque al decir `(?==)` le estás diciendo: devuélveme todo aquello que esté antes de un `=`. Hay dos opciones: usar `(?:==)` simplemente para hacer un "match" y que no se capture este grupo, o `(?=\=\=)` para hacer un look-ahead que busque texto seguido por `==`.

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Cierto! Muchas gracias. He editado la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta este comando en Bash:

```
cat requirements.txt | grep -oP "\w+[-_]{0,1}\w+"
```

`requirements.txt` sería el archivo de requerimientos pip.

Lo importante es la expresión regular a utilizar y la que pongo incluye el requerimiento del separador guión o guión bajo; actualicé el ejemplo de ***@A. Cedano*** para que lo veas en vivo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/AVCmvW/2).

Si necesitas guardar el resultado a un archivo (seguramente sí), puedes usar obviamente la redirección de salida; es decir:

```
cat requirements.txt | grep -oP "\w+[-_]{0,1}\w+" > salida.txt
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FerGarcia, mira este _pattern_, es posible usarlo con `grep`, no encuentro como . Y funciona: https://regex101.com/r/AVCmvW/4

Comment: El problema de tu patrón es la expresión regular. Una regex describe lo que quieres obtener y ahí estás especificando que estás buscando "n caracteres + dos símbolos '=' + otros n caracteres", que básicamente ¡es igual a la línea completa!; en otras palabras: tu regex no está especificando que buscas solamente la primer parte, sino que estás describiendo toda la cadena completa.

Comment: Es que en este regex para Python `(?P<paquete>.+)(==)(?P<version>.+)` solo debería tomar el grupo `paquete`, pensé que se podía hacer algo asi. solo el primer grupo.

Comment: Nótese que `cat fichero |grep ...` es innecesario: `grep ... fichero` es más que suficiente. Luego, `[-_]{0,1}` es más fácil de entender con `[-_]?`. Puestos a utilizar `grep`, con la regex `'^[^=]+` ya tienes suficiente: busca todo aquello que aparezca hasta `=`. La solución actual fallaría con una línea del tipo `hola-que-tal==1.2.3`.

Answer (score 1):

La alternativa en Python es como sigue:

```
import re


r = re.compile('(?P<paquete>.+)(==)(?P<version>.+)'
for l in open('base.txt').readlines():
    print (r.search(l).group('paquete'))
```

- En la primera línea se importa el módulo `re` que se encarga de las expresiones regulares.
- Ya que vamos a aplicar la misma búsqueda a todas las líneas, creamos un objeto `pattern` o *patrón de búsqueda* con la expresión que buscamos:

  - El primer grupo tiene nombre `paquete` y se forma con cualquier caracter y cualquier cantidad.
  - El segundo grupo solo es un separador, formado por los signos de igualdad.
  - El tercer grupo tiene por nombre `version` y se forma por el resto de los caracteres después del segundo grupo.
- Recorremos el archivo de requisitos, línea por línea,
- Y la pasamos como argumento a la búsqueda (que usa el objeto compilado previamente) y solo se imprime el resultado del grupo `paquete` (o sea el *match*).

Comment: Desde el momento que todo lo que sigue a `==` no te interesa, puedes prescindir de recogerlo y decir directamente `'(?P<paquete>.+)=='`.